# How to use LINQ to reduce a <string,list<string>> to <string,string>?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm calling a method with a return type of `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

The way i'm calling it i expect the `List<string>` to always have just 1 string element. To simplify this i'd like to use Linq to convert the return type to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

I got as far as to use `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Value);` but i'm stumped on how to get the correct values. Is a conversion like this possible with LINQ?

Comment: Can't you modify the method that returns the Dictionary so that it returns `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: It's a method in another program which i can't easily modify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Value.FirstOrDefault());
```

The value of your dictionary is a `List<string>`, so you can use [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckzcawb8(v=vs.110).aspx) extension methods. Now there is several options to get the first element. Take a look this [article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/E23I160714-Understanding-Single,-SingleOrDefault,-First-and-FirstOrDefault.html) for more details

Comment: It might be good to explain the difference between using `FirstOrDefault` vs `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: I'd suggest using `.First` instead of `.FirstOrDefault`.  Since the OP always seems to expect one result, it would probably be better to have it throw an error if there are no results.

Comment: @BradleyUffner If they always expect one then `Single` should be used.

Comment: @JamieR I'd still use `SingleOrDefault`, *just in case*

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Depends on the requirements, from what OP has posted he only ever expects 1, so I would think `Single` would have been appropriate. But I understand, it's null vs exception.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath  That depends.  If getting exactly one results is the only valid path, then it should throw an error; in the `.SingleOrDefault` case, it  just ends up sweeping the error under the rug, and leads to a nasty bug hunt later.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Of course, that depends entirely on the OP's requirements

Comment: Short of hearing back directly from the OP on that, the 2nd paragraph seems to strongly suggest that anything other than 1 result is an error.

Comment: hi @cFrozenDeath and @JameR, I left my answer using `FirstOrDefault` because the OP doesn't specify  what he/she wants to do in case there is more than one element. But, as you are discussing in your comments, all depends on the OP's requirements, that's why I recommend to read the article.

Comment: Wouldn't all this chatting represent the question's level of **too broad**/**unclear what you are asking** ?